# bash 5.1.4 associative array with period in index works for one statement but not in another

Tags: arrays, bash

As the title says, my index with a period in the name is properly set in one call to the function but not when referencing the index to assign a value. I only found one other question and the answer was to declare the array as associative. (Which I already had.)

The relevant part of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

 declare -Ag root_dict sub_dict1 sub_dict2 
 object=0.7.0-rc1                           #parsed from file

_set_key $object
# called from another part of script 

_set_key() { 

if [[ -z $last_obj ]]; then            # first object parsed.
    root_dict_key="$object"            
    last_obj="$object"
    last_key="$object"
    object=""

    root_dict[$root_dict_key]=""        # i haven't parsed the value yet
    last_dict=root_dict
    last_key=root_dict_key
    return

elif [[ -n $sub_dict ]]; then 
                                        # parsed another object to get the array value.
                                        # value is also a key, to reference another array.
    object=files                        # argument sent with caller

                                        # indirect referencing because the referenced array \ 
    dict_key="${!last_dict}"            # is dynamic
    dict_key[$last_key]="$object"
    last_obj="$object"
    last_val="$object"
    object=""
    return

fi
}
```

The first `if` statement properly sets the key. `root_dict[0.7.0-rc1]=""`

When I go to set the value for that key in the next call to `_set_key` and the `elif` statement I get:

```
line 136: 0.7.0-rc2: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".7.0-rc2")
```

I know variable names can't have punctuation except for the underscore, but the other answer suggested that associative array indices are string literals. Why would the index get properly set in the first call but return the error in the second call? The caller is the same in both instances first sending `object=0.7.0-rc1` and then `object=files`.

Comment: check your script with shellcheck.net, it has issues the linter will show you

Comment: You must define the function `_set_key` before calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code maybe you wanted to write

```
dict_key="${!last_dict}"
root_dict_key[$last_key]="$object"
```

... instead of ...

```
dict_key="${!last_dict}"
dict_key[$last_key]="$object"
```

`dict_key` was not declare as an associative array. When bash sees the assignment `dict_key[$last_key]="$object"` (note the `[…]`) then the non-associative `dict_key` is interpreted as a regular array.

The braces of regular arrays open an arithmetic context. Bash arithmetic contexts cannot interpret floating point numbers, hence the error message.